# Android Studio shows wrong layout in layout preview (ActionBarOverlayLayout?!)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a nice **FrameLayout** as main container and **some other views** inside it's hierarchy.

But **the preview shows a simple ActionBarOverlayLayout.**

What is that? Why is it here?

I have Android Studio 3.0.0

I have tried:
Restart Android Studio. Refresh the preview by resizing. Changed the preview device, changed the SDK of the preview, changed the blueprint\design options, pressed "force refresh layout" `Button`.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp">


<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/walk_list_item_height"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="0%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="0%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    app:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/corner_radius"
    android:id="@+id/walk_iv" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/walk_name_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_duration_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration_tv"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#fff" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_marker"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stops_tv"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I created a new xml in my project using your xml and everything works fine. Have you tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it?

Comment: @Ibrahim Exactly where?

Comment: share your build.gradle

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, I have created a new layout with your XML and it is working fine. Try clean build and share your `build.gradle`

Comment: I've also tried your code and it works fine. Go ahead and run it it's probably working fine.

Comment: Is this a framelayout that will be call by a fragment? And i think in your Activity layout, you have a `FrameLayout` that will call this fragment layout. Check again that activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to raise

> buildToolsVersion to 26.0.0

previous was bugged (25.0.2)

Answer (score 1):

That is because there is a broken build in your earlier build. It is coming from the intermediate files which is because the files are not proper in your xml files. There might be a broken link or a `-` in the drawables names.

Until you resolve this you cannot proceed to see the layout of your app in the layout-editor.

Moreover Android Studio will not show you any error in the error log or any other terminal.

Start from the styles/themes of the app, it might contain something which is missing from the gradle or resources of the project. Due to the support library still in the project it partially showcases it as missing control of XML files, but it will not let you load the xml editor visually for the project.

You have see that by yourself, start first from drawables and then move to values folder, if not check your gradle and then come back to Java files for the error.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and, In my case, it was simpler than that.  I just received a warning message recommending to remove the explict reference to the BuildToolsVerison from build.gradle file so I just did it, then saved all file, Menu >> Run >> Make a project and it worked fine.

[image: Warning message]

[image: The solution]